# How to switch databases in postgres?

Tags: postgresql

In SQL Server, I use:

```
 use database_name
 Go
 Select * from table_name
```

In postgreSQL, I still use:

```
 \connect database_name
 Select * from table_name
========================
then error: 
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "\"
LINE 1: \connect database_name
        ^
********** Error **********

ERROR: syntax error at or near "\"
SQL state: 42601
Character: 1.
```

Why?
Can do help me? Thanks.

Comment: Use PgAdmin - III call command.

Comment: You got errors because every command in psql CLI have to be terminated with ";" So, just do \connect database_name; And then, select * from table_name;

Answer (score 27):

Technically PostgreSQL can't switch databases. You must disconnect and reconnect to the new DB.

The `psql` command-line client will do this for you with the `\connect` command, shortcut `\c`. But these are not commands processed by the PostgreSQL server, they're client commands. Different clients won't understand or support them.

At a guess you're using PgAdmin-III, in which case [use the pulldown menu in the query tool to switch databases](http://www.sqlines.com/postgresql/pgadmin/change_database).

Some day I'd like to extract `psql`'s backslash-commands code into a library that things like PgAdmin could link to and use too.