# Postgres - run \c command in github actions

Tags: postgresql, github-actions

In GitHub actions, I am running a JavaScript file which connects to PostgreSQL and creates the  table and extension for the database.

my script looks like this:

```
const { Client } = require('pg')

const pgclient = new Client({
  host: process.env.POSTGRES_HOST,
  port: process.env.POSTGRES_PORT,
  user: process.env.POSTGRES_USER,
  password: process.env.POSTGRES_PASSWORD,
  database: process.env.POSTGRES_DB,
})

pgclient.connect()

const createDB = `
    drop database mydb;
    create database mydb;
    \c mydb;
    CREATE EXTENSION "pgcrypto";
`

pgclient.query(createDB, (err, res) => {
  if (err) throw err
  pgclient.end()
})
```

When I run the script, I get an error

```
error: syntax error at or near "c"
```

Which I am guessing is coming from `\c` flag.

How do I use PostgreSQL commands like this?

Comment: is it that you have to escape the \?  Therefore \\c ?

Comment: @Carter changed `\c` to `\\c` and now I get `syntax error at or near "\"` haha

Comment: what if you just type in there instead connect to mydb.  I think the issue is you might be mixing command line and SQL, but you are in sql at that point not in a command line it seems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can not use \c here because it is a psql meta-command, which I think you do not use here: See https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-psql.html.

You need to reconnect to the new DB like so:

```
const pgclient_mydb = new Client({
  host: process.env.POSTGRES_HOST,
  port: process.env.POSTGRES_PORT,
  user: process.env.POSTGRES_USER,
  password: process.env.POSTGRES_PASSWORD,
  database: 'mydb',
})

pgclient_mydb.connect()
```

See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/43670984/10743176